# Add multiple nodes to datagridview

Tags: c#, xml, windows-forms-designer

My database is similar to this:

```
enter code here
<data> 
  <Var1> 
    <ID>test</ID> 
    <Value>...</Value>
  </Var1> 
  <Var2> 
    <ID>abc</ID>
    <Value>123</Value>
  </Var2> 
</data>
```

Can I add all of the Var nodes to a Datagridview? Or I have to put them into one node like this:

```
<data>
  <Var>
    <ID>test</ID>
    <Value>...</Value>
  </Var>
  <Var>
    <ID>abc</ID>
    <Value>123</Value>
  </Var>
</data>
```

I can display them with one node but I want to separate them into multiple nodes them display them all in a datagridview. here my code

```
 XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(@"my xml file");
        string path= @"my xml file";
        DataSet tab = new DataSet();
        tab.ReadXml(path);
        //database
        //dataGridView1.DataSource = tab.Tables[0];
        //dataGridView1.DataSource = tab.Tables[1];
        dataGridView1.DataSource = tab;
        dataGridView1.DataMember ="Var1";
        dataGridView1.DataMember = "Var2";
```

Comment: what have you tried so far.  perhaps posting your code would facilitate us understanding your question - I for one am perplexed

Comment: Do not put code in the comments! Edit the question. Also: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page! - Also: __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView` or a `DataGrid` and vice versa!! This is wrong and confusing as those are different controls. Always call things by their __right__ name!

Comment: A DGV is a flat object with row and columns.  So the first level of an xml is usually the Data Table name in your case is "data".  The next level in your case is the rows which is "Var".  Then the next level is the column names like "ID" and "Value".  Then the value for each cell is the innertext of the column name tags.

Comment: I meant can I display var1, var2 in one DGV or I have to put them in one (var) then display it?